# ngx-formly template "pdfviewer" using inside my custom input template

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I create a ngx-formly template to choose pdf file and visualize it with inside using another template "custom input file"

This is the main form declaration:

```
fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
  {
    key: 'pdfsource',
    type: 'pdfviewer',
    templateOptions: {      
      label: 'Choose pdf file',
      placeholder: 'choose File',
      required: true,
    }
  },
]
```

I get this error:
ERROR
Error: [Formly Error] There is no type by the name of "undefined"

This is the stackbiz 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-bootstrap-htuh7z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solutions:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-bootstrap-mcvzfp
https://ngx-formly-ui-bootstrap-mcvzfp.stackblitz.io

this is the model structure:

```
  model = {
    file:{
      filename: 'name.pdf',
      filevalue: null
    }
```

and formlyconfig:

```
fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
  {
    key: 'file',
    type: 'pdfviewerinput',
    templateOptions: {      
      label: 'Choose File',
      placeholder: 'choose File',
      filename: 'filename',
      filevalue: 'filevalue',
      required: true,
    }
  }]
```

ngx-formly template pdfviewerinput include:

- ngx-formly template pdfviewer -> to visualize pdf
- ngx-formly template    inputfile -> to choose file